# Combine vector with different lengths in R

Tags: r

> FIRST SITUATION:

I have the vectors v1 and v2
v1 <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15)
v2 <- c(3, 4, 5, 23, NA, 14, NA)

I want to create a function (I don't want want use r functions for these 3 cases) to sum each values and because the length is different, I want to put a 0 in this missing places.

### As a result, i would like to have:
4, 6, 9, 28, NA, 22, NA, 11, 13, 15

> SECOND SITUATION

I want to sum each values, just like the first situation, but the sum action must stop when reaches the last value of the smaller vector.

### As a result, it would be:
4, 6, 9, 28, NA, 22, NA

> THIRD SITUATION

I want to combine each values and repeat them when the there is a smaller one.

As a result, it would be:
4, 6, 9, 28, NA, 22, NA, 14, 17, 20

Comment: What have you tried so far? And, what issues did you run into with your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the length same

```
mx <- max(length(v1), length(v2))
c(v2, rep(0, mx - length(v2))) + c(v1, rep(0, mx - length(v1)))
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA 11 13 15
```

For second situation, use `min`

```
mn <- min(length(v1), length(v2))
v2[seq_len(mn)] + v1[seq_len(mn)]
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA
```

---

Or for third situation

```
c(v2, v2[seq_len(mx - length(v2))]) + c(v1, v1[seq_len(mx - length(v1))])
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA 14 17 20
```

---

It can be converted to a function

```
 f1 <- function(vec1, vec2, method = "min") {
       switch(method, 

           min = {
                  mn <- min(length(vec1), length(vec2))
                  vec1[seq_len(mn)] + vec2[seq_len(mn)]
                  },
            max = {
                 mx <- max(length(vec1), length(vec2))
                 c(vec2, rep(0, mx - length(vec2))) + c(vec1, rep(0, mx - length(vec1)))},
             recycle = {
               mx <- max(length(vec1), length(vec2))
                c(vec2, vec2[seq_len(mx - length(vec2))]) + c(vec1, vec1[seq_len(mx - length(vec1))])
             })
         }


f1(v1, v2)
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA
f1(v1, v2, "max")
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA 11 13 15
f1(v1, v2, "recycle")
#[1]  4  6  9 28 NA 22 NA 14 17 20
```